# Equipment recommendation for sound source localisation

Tags: equipment, localisation, microphone

Do you have any recommendation for multichannel equipment for source localization? What parameters should I consider for the microphones, for the recorder? Also any advice for starting multichannel analyses?

edits: I was thinking of crickets species, so pretty small source of sound, signals between 4-7 kHz. I am looking for having the 3D coordinates of the source of the crickets call.

Comment: Please edit the question to add more context - what species, what are the sound characteristics, what range do you wish to achieve, do you need 3D co-ordinates, where can you practically place the microphones etc.?

Comment: Please add information on area of interest (max distance) and if you can surround the crickets with microphones.

Answer (score 1):

I don't do air acoustics but this is a good paper that might be worth looking into for microphone setups. Good luck!
https://besjournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/2041-210X.12291

Comment: It would be extremely beneficial to at least add some brief explanation of the "solution" proposed in the link. This way, your answer will serve both as a starting point for someone and a future reference for people.

Answer (score 1):

There's also a pretty comprehensive review of terrestrial sound source localisation here [Rhinehart et al., 2020](https://doi.org/10.1002/ece3.6216)

Comment: It would be extremely beneficial to at least add some brief explanation of the "solution" proposed in the link. This way, your answer will serve both as a starting point for someone and a future reference for people.